# Does iron nail sink in rubbing alcohol

Tags: density

I have been trying for so long to get answer[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, iron sinks in rubbing alcohol, water and in any liquid with density lower than density of iron.

It would float e.g in melted lead or gold.

For a very light iron/steel pieces like needles,, or pieces very flat like a classical Gillette razor blade, they could stay afloat on water due surface tension. But this is seldom case for alcohols, as their surface tension is several times smaller.

Comment: I firmly believe that the knowledge of iron's ability to sink in water, when it comes into one's mind, deserves more **heft** than a mere forum message. One should learn it the hard way, by drowning an axe in the river or something like that. Therefore, though your answer is correct and otherwise good, I have mixed feelings about it.

Comment: I prefer dropping a camera from the canoe, but it is indecisive, as cameras are seldom a stainless steel cases these days. Sometimes it is hard to imagine one does not know the answer yet, where one reaches a stack exchange site. BTW, I do like your comments, seen in various topics.

Comment: That can be pretty instructive too, though cameras hardly contain much iron, if any at all. My concern, however, is of different nature. Some questions tend to display the lack of certain underlying knowledge that pretty much makes the very question void, together with the answer. Imagine a person asking for a very specific piece of information and its location in a very specific book on the subject, and then adding a casual remark that reveals they are _illiterate_. That would instantly make you aware that their real problem is not there, but very many levels deep down below. Same thing here.

Comment: Yes, this was a thoughtful remark.